# High School Level Math Books?

Tags: reference-request

I am in grade 11 in Canada, going to be taking Functions next semester. In grade 12 I will be taking both Advanced Functions and Calculus/Vectors. Are there any good books that I could buy to prepare for these courses and get a good grip on the concepts that I will see in grade 11 and 12 math?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what does a course in "functions" typically cover?  Elementary Algebra?  Trig (/transcendental functions)?  Set Theory?  I'm just curious because we don't have a course called "Functions" down here in the States.

Comment: @Bye_World Functions covers Quadratic/Exponential/Sinusoidal functions, as well as focuses on Trig ratios, discreet functions, and equivalent algebraic expressions. Here's a link if you'd like more information; http://ontariomath.wikispaces.com/file/view/Math%20MCR3U%20curr.pdf/380065162/Math%20MCR3U%20curr.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to read *Functions and Graphs* by I. M. Gelfand, E. G. Glagoleva, and E. E. Shnol and *Trigonometry* by I. M. Gelfand and Mark Saul.  Gelfand's books *Algebra* and *The Method of Coordinates* are worth reading, if less relevant to what you want to study.

Another good option are the texts *Mathematics 1: Japanese Grade 10*, *Algebra and Geometry:  Japanese Grade 11*, and *Basic Analysis:  Japanese Grade 11* edited by Kunihiko Kodaira.

The texts mentioned above are challenging, but the exposition is clear.  You can use them to build conceptual understanding and develop your problem-solving skills.